# want to detect documentcompleted multiple times on geckowebbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, domdocument, gecko

I am working on webbrowser app on C# using geckowebbrowser. Here i give a url to navigate than detects document completed. After this i enter some values on textbox and click on a button. 
Now heres is my issue. At this point after clicking on the button i again wants to detect documentcompleted event and do something. Now how can i perform different task using a single event and single event handler.

```
        geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("www.facebook.com");
        geckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new   EventHandler<Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs>(geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

        GeckoHtmlElement ge= (GeckoHtmlElement)geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_5");
        ge.Click();
```

At this point i want to detect documentcompleted event and perform some other task. How to do this?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just put line 3&4 into `geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`.

Comment: I already did that. I may not be clear so let me clarify. After getting documentcomplete event, my code will click a button which will again navigate to other document.So now i want to detect the next (or second) document complete event and had to perform some other setattributes and click.

Answer (score 0):

Just add global variable to your class:

```
CurrentAction MyAction = CurrentAction.UNKNOWN;

public enum CurrentAction
{
    UNKNOWN = -1,
    ClickButtonOne,
    DoSomethingElse,
    ClickTheOtherButton,
    DoNothing,
}
```

Then before navigate to the first page, set this flag:

```
MyAction = CurrentAction.ClickButtonOne;
geckoWebBroser1.Navigate("site.com");
```

In `DocumentCompleted` event do this:

```
switch (MyAction)
{
    case ClickButtonOne:
        // find the button, check if not null
        MyAction = CurrentAction.DoSomethingElse; // set a new action
        button.Click();
        break;
    case DoSomethingElse:
        // Do something
        MyAction = CurrentAction.ClickTheOtherButton; // set a new action
        break;
    case ClickTheOtherButton:
        // this is the last page, so lets stop here
        MyAction = CurrentAction.DoNothing; // specific action
        break;           
    default:
        Debug.Assert(false); break;
}
```

So each time you will get into DocumentCompleted , the code will do different task. Just dont forget to set the action you need, and do null-checks. Also I recomend you do implement `NavigationError` event, so you will know if something went wrong.